# after creating/importing tsv, it returns zero results in athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I "imported" a .tsv and when I query it, it has 0 records.

I did run the:

MSCK REPAIR TABLE

I basically followed this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html#tsv-example

What could  I have done wrong?

Comment: Hi Chaicago1998,

You might wrongly created the table, or wrongly mentioned the partition. Thats why you are getting this error. 
Is this possible to share the example of your S3 structure?